# How to recursively add/remove child windows to/from parent window

Tags: c++, winapi

I created child windows recursively with a for loop and then destroying those recursively made child windows after i'm done with them.

I tried using `HWND *window` and keep looping and incrementing the pointer and initializing, but I keep getting an error of access violation.

```
HWND *window;

//adding child windows
for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    *window = CreateWindowW(L"static", L"Test", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 40, 
    i * 50, 100, 50, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    window++;
}

//removing child windows
for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    DestroyWindow(*window);
    window--;
}
```

It says write access violation `windows` was nullptr. I'm not sure how this is supposed to work. Is there a different way I can go about solving this?

Comment: It still did not work, it says access violation on the initialization not the reference. `error here -> *window10 = CreateWindowW(L"static", L"test", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 40, i * 50, 100, 50, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);`

Comment: Keep in my mind that child windows are automatically destroyed when parent is destroyed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the uninitialized pointer `HWND *window;` which is causing the access violation and using an array of 100 handles to fix the problem is not a good idea for a few reasons:

- You are only using 30 out of 100 handles
- You are statically allocating the handles

A better option would be to malloc your window handle array:

```
int window_amount = 30;

HWND *window = malloc(sizeof(HWND)*window_amount);

//adding child windows
for(int i = 0; i < window_amount; i++) {
    window[i] = CreateWindowW(L"static", L"Test", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 40, 
    i * 50, 100, 50, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    window++;
}

//removing child windows
for(int i = 0; i < window_amount; i++) {
    DestroyWindow(window[i]);
    window--;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, could I also malloc only when I need it later in a scope for example `HWND *window; { window = malloc(sizeof(HWND)*30); }`

Comment: That worked perfectly, reason why I got an error saying it is a `nullptr` is because I haven't allocated memory with `malloc`. I could also `free` and `malloc` again whenever I want to change allocation size.

Comment: Given that the question is tagged C++, `std::vector` would be far more appropriate. Or at least use `new[]` instead of `malloc`

Comment: You are right, but I just thought that since winapi was originally made for C very long ago, using the old C ways would maybe work better for windows.h

Answer (score -1):

Ok I solved it by using an array of HWND instead like this
`HWND window[100];`

```
for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    window[i] = CreateWindowW(L"static", L"Test", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 40, 
    i * 50, 100, 50, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}

//removing child windows
for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    DestroyWindow(window[i]);
}
```

Comment: You should never hard coded a constant in your code like that in your code. The time, you change the number of windows to 40, you will probably forget to modify one of those location and get another access violation. You should read about DRY principle (**Don't repeat yourself**). By the way, if you are writing your code in C++ (as tagged in your question), your should really used `std::vector<HWND>` instead.

Comment: @Phil1970 That is what i'm using right now, and it works a 100 times better, very easy to add and remove too.